# Code design - HTML getter and parser "design pattern"?

Tags: java, android

Im writing an app that gets the html source of a website, and parses a list of object X from it.

I wrote a class `HTMLGetter` and `HTMLParser`, `HTMLParser` returns the list of Xs.

After a few days this design seemed a bit wrong to me, I started thinking I should probably have one class which contains `HTMLGetter` as a subclass and this new class will return the list of Xs (basically make `HTMLGetter` a subclass of `HTMLParser`), we'll call this class `XsListGetter`.

However, now I'm not sure what to do with the HTTP response code returned from `HTMLGetter`.

I could throw some exception but then I break encapsulation of `XsListGetter`.
I could check the response code in `XsListGetter` and return null if some error occurred but then I lose the information as to what problem has occurred.

What is the right design here? is there a right design? maybe an entirely different one than the two I suggested?

Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer help you ? I'd love to hear your feedback :-)

Comment: Didnt really like the static methods suggestion but nice idea overall so thanks. Still feels a bit "dirtier" than it can be, not sure why though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little bit of a personal opinion, by here's what I would do:

Have a single class, lets call it `XsListGetter`, as you suggested. You could make it a singleton, or have it as a static class (have all methods static).

Then, have one method to actually fetch the data, which will:

- Fetch the HTML source from the URL you provided, and put it in a private String variable in the class.
- Put the HTTP status code in another private variable.
- If it fails altogether (eg. no internet connection), record that too.

Secondly, have another method which checks if the request was successful, which would check if the request failed completely and if the status code is correct.

Thirdly, have a method which parses the HTML String into your list of objects.

Some pseudocode to describe what I mean:

```
class XsListGetter {
    private String sourceHtml;
    private boolean requestSucceeded = false;
    private int httpStatusCode = 0;

    public void fetchHtml(String url) {
        try {
            sourceHtml = //get the HTML as a string from the url
            httpStatusCode = //get the status code of the request, will be 200 if successful
            requestSucceeded = true //if we get here, we were successful
        } catch (IoException e) {
            requestSucceeded = false //otherwise, we didn't succeed
        }
    }

    public boolean requestSucceeded { //allow to check if the request succeeded
        return requestSucceeded && httpStatusCode == 200;
    }

    public List<MyItem> parseHtmlToList() {
        return parseHtmlStringToList(sourceHtml); //parse your Html to a list of items here
    }
}
```

Then, in your calling code, you can use it like this:

```
XsListGetter getter = new XsListGetter();
getter.fetchHtml();
if (getter.requestSucceeded() {
    myObjectsList = getter.parseHtmlToList();
} else {
    //Show helpful error message
}
```

Of course, there are many different ways to do this, and mine may not be the best :-)

Some things to note:

- If you are not using a HTML parser, use one ! I'd recommend Jsoup.
- You should experiment, and if you find a better way, do it that way.
- I don't know exactly what you are doing, so this may not be the best way.
- There is no "right" design - there are many ways to do this, and each has advantages and drawbacks.

Hope this helps :-)